# Facing challenges aligning TextViews in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am unable to align TextViews inside a RelativeLayout which exists under a LinearLayout programmatically.

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
       relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView operationType = new TextView(getActivity());
        operationType.setId(View.generateViewId());
        operationType.setText(strOperationType);
        operationType.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        relativeLayout.addView(operationType);

        TextView operationDate = new TextView(getActivity());
        operationDate.setText(strOperationDate);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLLP=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rLLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,operationType.getId());
        **//rLLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,operationType.getId()); but this pushes the LinearLayout with "C" character displayed in below picture**
        operationDate.setLayoutParams(rLLP);
        relativeLayout.addView(operationDate);

        innerLLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

As you can see from below picture, i want date to placed at rightside of Surgery and center of the remaining space, not just after Surgery.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works.

```
operationDate.setGravity(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

Comment: Still getting the same result. Date immediately follows after Surgery

Comment: Try changing this line.

operationType.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

then add operationDate.setGravity(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line.

```
operationType.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Then add

```
operationDate.setGravity(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```